# child not updating based on props in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have something like this in my parent scope:

```
<form-error :errors="errors"></form-error>
<textarea class="form-control" name="post" cols="30" rows="8" @keydown="errors.clear('post')" v-model="post"></textarea>
```

Note the `@keydown` event, where I am clearing out the errors, by calling
method on a class.
With `:errors="errors"` I am passing instance of the below `Errors` class,
into `<form-error>` child component:

```
class Errors {
    constructor() {
        this.errors = {};
    }

    get(field) {
        if (this.errors[field]) {
            return this.errors[field][0];
        }
    }

    clear(field) {
        delete this.errors[field];
    }
    has(field) {
        return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
    }
}
```

And in `<form-error>` child component I have this:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="errors.has('post')" class="alert alert-danger" v-text="errors.get('post')"></div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['errors']
    };
</script>
```

Now, while `v-text="errors.get('post')"` works fine, and I am getting error
displayed, the `v-if="errors.has('post')"` part doesn't work at all.

I am assuming `errors` is passed the right way as props, otherwise that
`errors.get('post')` wouldn't work.

Question is, why when parent triggers that `@keydown` event, and I see the
errors object is being emptied properly (Vue addon for chrome), the `v-if`
part doesn't update, thus hiding the div?

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the `<FormError>` child component is being updated to reflect the change in `errors` when I start typing, but still `v-if` doesn't trigger.

**Edit**

What's even more confusing, docs say:

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the
>   prop is an array or object(as in my case), mutating the object or array itself inside the
>   child will affect parent state.

Although of course I am not mutating the object from with in my child, but the
important part is that object changes in parent should be reflected in child.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error. As I can see [Map.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has#Browser_compatibility) has poor support in browsers. You can try using any of following alternatives:

**post in errors**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="'post' in errors" class="alert alert-danger" v-text="errors.get('post')"></div>
</template>
```

**errors['post']**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="errors['post'] !== undefined" class="alert alert-danger" v-text="errors.get('post')"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: But this is not Map, it's just a custom class method wrapper around `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @branquito You can use `hasOwnProperty` as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think we are on the same page here. I AM using hasOwnProperty and it does not work( hint: look at that Error class). Aside from that, that same directive `v-if="errors.has('post')` works fine when moved into `<form-error v-if="errors.has('post')" :errors=errors></form-error>`.